# how to automate login to a website in Android using Jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

Very Basic. but i know how to connect to webpage in java the thing which i don't know that how to deal with buttons(Login button) and username(text filed) and password(text field)in android

Answer (score 1):

Just treat it as a form and pass the login credentials using POST method to the page which is mentioned in the action attribute of the login form.

When dealing with buttons, simply get the text from `getText()` for `EditText` and then in `onClickListener()` of the button, fetch the information from `jsoup` functions by passing the above info as the `POST` parameters.

Comment: Then no need to make the XML Layout?

Comment: No need if you don't want users to input the details instead you want to hardcode them

Comment: yes.. i see..!
now see What's the problem with this code..

response = Jsoup.connect("https://uogis.uog.edu.pk/Default.aspx?You%20are%20logout%20now.%20Please%20login%20again!")
            .data("txtLogin", user.getText())
            .data("txtPassword", pass.getText())
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();